# Why does the material-icons i element overlap the adjacent input element?

Tags: material-design

I am not sure if this is a material related code or not.
But if you see this code, you'll find that the width of the `i` element is wider than that displayed by the red border. You cannot navigate to the beginning of the text input as it still points to the material icon, help_circle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<style type="text/css">
div.tipped-small
{
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-right:10px;    
    display:inline-block;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:50%;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    overflow:none;
}
div.tipped-small i
{
    width:15px;
    color:#4857BA;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:15px;
    cursor:pointer;    
    position:absolute;
    overflow:none;
}    
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="tipped-small">
        <i class="material-icons" style="border:1px solid red">help_circle</i>        
    </div>    
    <input type="text" style="height:15px;border:1px solid red"/>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/anjanesh/pen/LqYXZe

How do I get the **i** tag to be only 15px ?

Comment: Tags are markup. You're referring to *elements*.

Comment: `none` isn't a valid value for the `overflow` property. Changing it to `hidden` [resolves your issue](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/omNVBq?editors=1100), though I'm not sure why it's behaving like it is. If I inspect the `i` element it doesn't appear to overlap the input.

Comment: It did work ! Thanks. But this definitely was a strange behaviour.

Comment: I think a simpler demonstration would be to just use `<i class="material-icons" style="border:1px solid red">help_circle</i>` and see that the right border is beyond the icon's portion.

Comment: I used help_outline instead of help_circle and it stopped the horizontal overflow