# Why does the help_circle element in material icons have a wider container?

Tags: material-design

This is a spin-off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54310673/why-does-the-material-icons-i-element-overlap-the-adjacent-input-element?noredirect=1#comment95443994_54310673) - to the point and no css.
Why is the question mark icon (help_circle) having a wider container ?

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<i class="material-icons" style="border:1px solid red;">help_circle</i>    
<i class="material-icons" style="border:1px solid red;">delete_forever</i>
<i class="material-icons" style="border:1px solid red;">insert_chart</i>
```

[image]